# Clonezilla using dd on Fedora 16 LVM

Tags: fedora, clonezilla

I'm trying to do a disk to disk clone of a 500GB Fedora 16 installation using Clonezilla, but it keeps using dd to copy the root ext4 LVM, and is doing so very slowly (~375MB/minute, 24hrs total copy time). I have maybe 100GB of data on this drive.

I've used Clonezilla to copy CentOS 6 box with a similar setup (1 root LVM with ext4), and it correctly copied just the files and didn't use dd to copy all sectors.  Does Fedora 16 have something other than LVM2, or is the GPT messing up Clonezilla's recognition of ext4 on LVM?

OR, what should I use to more quickly clone a Fedora 16 installation?

EDIT: The LVM is definitely not encrypted.

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue. I've been using clonezilla before to clone my Fedora 15 installations and it only took time to clone the used hard disk not the free space, But in case of Fedora 16 it is doing whole cloning Any help would be appreciated TIA

Comment: Glad to hear I'm not the only one. It may have something to do with the switch from MBR to GPT, since Fedora 15 and CentOS 6 both use ext4 on top of LVM and Clonezilla correctly copies them.